# How to make a <div> full display when display equal to flex?

Tags: html, css

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <h1>A</h1>
      <p>clap</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h1>W</h1>
      <p>clap</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h1>S</h1>
      <p>clap</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h1>D</h1>
      <p>clap</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h1>Q</h1>
      <p>clap</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h1>E</h1>
      <p>clap</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h1>R</h1>
      <p>clap</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

how to (.containeri) full screen with flex display?
I want full window full height and width with flex?

I use height 100% but it is not full window with flex property.but in grid it is 100% window with height anf width

Comment: try `flex:1` or `flex: 1 0 100%` on children

Comment: `display: grid;` is not `display: flex` ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [mre] showing what you've tried so far. Please include HTML as well as CSS. You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to make it runnable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set `shrink` to `0` to prevent the flex items from shrinking:

```
.container {
    display: flex;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("asso-myron-HZCBJmlUPas-unsplash.jpg");
}

.flex-item {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

An example:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-item {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item">
        1
      </div>       
    </div>
```

Comment: But I need 100% background of the window

Comment: @KaustavBasu ok, I added it:)

Comment: html,
body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
}
.container {
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: yellow;
}

.box {
 flex-shrink: 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

.container {
    height:100vh;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    object-fit:cover;
    display: flex;
    background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSxD1r0WianEq0iQy_H8INxLhdpmcz6c_DslA&usqp=CAU");
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I want to use flex not grid

Comment: What do you want, exactly. 100% width and height?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="d-flex p-3 bg-secondary flex-shrink-0 text-white">
    <div class="p-2 bg-info">Flex item 1</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I think you want this.
If not then Kindly attach html code.